# Detect focus lost from different input in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, angular8

I have 2 inputs, one of them has a numeric value on it:

```
<input matInput class="form-control"
                [(value)]="row.value"
                ([ngModel])="row.value">
```

The second input calculates that value -20€ value.

```
<input matInput class="form-control"
                value="{{ row.value - 20 | round }}"
                ([ngModelChange])="row.value">
```

And I also apply a `round` filter. The result is this:

[image]

When I change the value on the first input (column `Retail value`), I would like to be able to capture it from the second input (`Total cost`) and recalculate it. The most angularish way possible.

So my question is:

What is the best Angularish way to do this?

*Edit:* I should have said that my inputs are located insidte a material table:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="table">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
       <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Retail Value </mat-header-cell>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <input matInput class="form-control"
                [(value)]="row.value"
                ([ngModel])="row.value"
                (ngModelChange)="updateTotal(row)">
       </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
       <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Retail Value </mat-header-cell>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <input matInput class="form-control"
                [(value)]="row.total">
       </td>
    </ng-container>
</mat-table>
```

And my *.ts* function:

```
updateTotal(row: RepairItem) {
   row.total = row.value - row.discount;
}
```

Comment: `(blur)` event handler on the control losing focus?

Comment: on the first input and then make a calculation on typescript? That's the most Angularish?

Comment: Just realised I mis-read the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently 2-way binding the input value to your model using `[(ngModel)]`. To listen to value changes you can handle `(ngModelChange)` events.

component.html

```html
<input matInput class="form-control"
                [(ngModel)]="row.value"
                (ngModelChange)="onModelChange(row)">
```

component.ts

```js
onModelChange(row) {
  // row.value has been updated to the new value
  // you also have a reference to the original row, 
  //   should you need to do anything with it
  console.log(row.value);
}
```

Comment: Okay gonna update my question as it's a bit more complex as my inputs are inside a material table...

Comment: Why does it make it more complex? Excuse my ignorance - I don't use Material.

Comment: Because I'm generating dynamic rows for the tables. And each row is binded as the example before. Gonna check your example anyways because it should work somehow.

Comment: Just had a look at `matInput`. Firstly: I'm going to remain far away from Material. Secondly: looks like you need to look into how you work with material forms. You should use one of `matInput` or `[(ngModel)]` - the 2 aren't compatible. I created a very simple demo using `[(ngModel)]` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4usmfi